# Android TV - SearchBar focus

Tags: android, searchbar, android-tv, leanback

I use custom search screen in my tv app, and my problem is that I can't set the focus on `SearchBar` view when starting the fragment. I've tried the following approaches :

```
mSearchBar.setFocusable(true);
mSearchBar.requestFocus();
```

also tried in xml

```
<android.support.v17.leanback.widget.SearchBar
    android:id="@+id/search_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:focusable="true">
    <requestFocus />
</android.support.v17.leanback.widget.SearchBar>
```

and this

```
mSearchBar.setSearchQuery("");
```

nothing of above set the focus for `SearchBar`

Comment: Does making setFocusableInTouchMode() to true as well fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about Leanback's SearchFragment, then
try this in your search activity:

```
searchEditText = (SearchEditText) findViewById(R.id.lb_search_text_editor);
searchEditText.requestFocus();
```